# Pre-Processing Wi-Fi Channel State Information (CSI) Data

Tags: python, denoising, butterworth, preprocessing, pca

I was successfully able to collect some CSI data using the existing tool(s) on GitHub (https://github.com/StevenMHernandez/ESP32-CSI-Tool). The CSI data is a pair of imaginary and real number which can use to extract amplitude and phase information. However,  I have no prior knowledge of digital signal processing and I'm not sure how can to preprocess the CSI data to remove environmental noise like the Butterworth filter and/or PCA. I'm using Python and would like to know if this is an appropriate tool.

I'm trying to recreate steps from the following papers related to human activity detection using Wi-Fi CSI:

- SEARE: A System for Exercise Activity Recognition and Quality Evaluation Based on Green Sensing **URL:** https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8247258
- WiFi Sensing with Channel State Information: A Survey **URL:** https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3310194

Comment: CSI doesn't include noise information; it describes the linear channel, not the additive noise. Also, not quite sure what you want to remove noise from – the CSI is *not* the signal. None of what you write makes too much sense. Maybe you need to take a step back and describe from a higher-up perspective what you want to do and achieve; I doubt what you're considering so far takes you any closer to that goal.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I'm trying to recreate the steps mentioned in papers relating to activity detection using Wi-Fi CSI. Papers suggest after collecting CSI it's good to pass it through Butterworth filter to remove high-frequency noise.

Comment: which papers? which steps? I can't imagine a single case where Butterworth filtering on OFDM taps (i.e. CSI estimates) makes *any* sense for a time-variant channel, so I'd really recommend you link to the papers here.

Comment: Generally, please **edit** your question to describe, including concrete citations/links to your papers, what you're doing! this would make it much, much more possible to help you :)

Comment: I have edited my question to support my question :)

Comment: "I have no prior knowledge of digital signal processing" I highly recommend acquiring "Digital Signal Processing in Modern Communication Systems" by Schwarzinger. It's inexpensive, very approachable, and will give you some of the backdround you need.