# Analysing of CSI Matrix from received from ESP32 antennas

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, python

I am working on a project to sense human occupancy in a room. For that, I have been recommended to use the CSI signals from the WIFI. I have followed https://github.com/StevenMHernandez/ESP32-CSI-Tool to get the CSI data. I have got the following CSI Matrix,

[112 -128 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 9 2 10 1 12 0 14 1 14 1 16 2 16 3 16 3 16 4 15 5 15 5 14 5 13 4 12 2 11 1 11 0 11 -1 11 -2 12 -3 13 -3 14 -3 15 -2 16 -1 17 0 17 1 17 0 0 2 15 2 14 2 14 1 12 0 12 -1 12 -2 12 -4 12 -4 13 -4 15 -4 16 -4 17 -3 18 -3 19 -1 19 0 19 1 18 2 17 1 16 2 15 0 14 -1 14 -2 13 -3 14 -4 15 -6 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]

The documentation https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/wifi.html says to use the following chart to make sense of the above matrix. The documentation says,

> Each channel frequency response of sub-carrier is recorded by two bytes of signed characters. The first one is imaginary part and the second one is real part. There are up to three fields of channel frequency responses according to the type of received packet. They are legacy long training field (LLTF), high throughput LTF (HT-LTF) and space time block code HT-LTF (STBC-HT-LTF). For different types of packets which are received on channels with different state, the sub-carrier index and total bytes of signed characters of CSI is shown in the following table.

I dont have much prior knowledge in the field. Could any one help me understand this or point me to some useful resource.

[image: Table]

Comment: A single CSI matrix tells you nothing about the presence of a person in a room. Did they recommend you estimate e.g. breathing-induced periodic CSI changes, or what was the recommendation precisely?

Comment: By the way, you've got another person working *exactly* on the same problem using *exactly* the same hardware: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74413/pre-processing-wi-fi-channel-state-information-csi-data Maybe you want to team up with them.

Comment: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1550147718805718 . The recommendation is based on this paper. Here is a quote from the paper, 'In the first part, the access points are used as the transmitters, and the receivers are existing devices at home (e.g. laptop computer), which need to be equipped with Intel WiFi 5300. Raw CSI values are collected from a chip set firmware to receive packets.
For the second part, various data preprocessing methods are applied to the raw CSI stream for the minimization of interference from environment noise'. Then we feed it to a machine learning model.

Comment: Its not just using CSI signals, we will be using machine learning as well. However, instead of using Intel Wifi 5300 NIC, I am using an esp32, which gives a matrix as presented in the question. I would be glad to understand how to interpret this matrix.

Comment: Thank you for recommending the other person who is working on the same project.